# Autorenaming duplicate filename downloads in chrome/puppeteer/ubuntu

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, ubuntu, puppeteer, nautilus

I'm downloading pdf files using headFULL chromium & puppeteer. I call a javascript function in the browser context and the download starts. The file name comes as is from the server. Issue: Many files I download in a directory are of same names coming from the server and Chrome instead of autosuffixing an index (1) to the file, overwrites the existing one.

Since the file is downloaded by calling a JS function and I have inspected the function as well, I don't have access to a the pdf url. It is triggered using the function call and thus I have no control over the file names.
I have a list of the file names but that in no way helps in changing the filename on the fly, if it it's duplicate name already exists on the machine.

Config: Ubuntu 18.04, Puppeteer 1.18.1
I know either it's a config issue with Nautilus file manager or with Chrome. Is it possible to configure any of these two?

I cannot foresee an option within nodejs where I can rename the file before it's downloaded. A workaround is to download each file in a temp folder, then move it to the required folder while doing a check if it already exists and rename if so. But it adds a lot of time complexity. It would be great to have chrome or nautilus do the task.

Function which triggers the download:
await page.evaluate( (doc_index,arg1,arg2) => openDocument(String(doc_index), String(arg1), String(arg2) ,'ABC','','','XYZ') , doc_index,arg1,arg2 )

Expected behaviour: When the above function is called and pdf starts downloading in the set folder, if a pdf of the same name exists, the new pdf should be renamed to something like pdf_name.pdf(1) or the like.